# Cassandra 3.3 - Remote connection via cqlsh

Tags: cassandra, centos7, cassandra-3.0

I am facing some issues trying to connect to Cassandra 3.3.0 on Centos 7 remotely from another machine in the network. It is returning a "timed out" error while trying to connect via

```
$ cqlsh 192.168.1.56 9042
```

Same with:

```
$ cqlsh 192.168.1.56
```

In my point of view, I have configured the `cassandra.yaml` file correctly as it worked fine when I tried to connect to a locally running VM (Ubuntu) with an active Cassandra instance.

When I am checking the IPs and ports which have been bound via `netstat -lnt`, it is returning

```
tcp6   0   0   192.168.1.56:9042   :::*    Listen
```

Actually the only one which is bound to tcp6. `192.168.1.56:9160` is bound to `tcp`.

Running on Ubuntu, it returns the same binding to `tcp`. So the fault is related to that point, I guess.

Some background facts:

- I am running Cassandra as root. Both server and clients are running cqlsh 5.0.1, CQL spec 3.4.0 and Cassandra 3.3.0. Python 2.7.5.
- The VM is accessible via `192.168.1.56` without problems. Firewall is deactivated and I even have tried to de- and reactivate IPv6. I have tried different combinations configuring the `cassandra.yaml` -- such as taking the interface instead of its IP directly, but without changes in the result.

All my research has not shown success so far. Has anybody an idea?!

Comment: How are you trying to connect? Edit your post and add the remote cqlsh command you're using . It should look like this $ cqlsh xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx with no port unless you have a non default port configured. Also what version of cqlsh and Python are you running

Comment: Remote cqlsh commands have been added. I tried both - with and without port statement.
Both server and clients are running cqlsh 5.0.1, CQL spec 3.4.0 and Cassandra 3.3.0. Python in both 2.7.5

Comment: cqlsh should be using thrift at 9160 not 9042. Run these commands and put the results in your original post . $ sudo netstat -p | grep 9160  and also run $sudo netstat -p | grep :9042. If 9160 comes back null that is your issue. Also, what does your cassandra log say?

Comment: @apesa, he did not mention thrift. The correct port is `9042` as shown in the question?!

Answer (score 0):

Problem has been solved due to network misconfiguration.
I've changed the below configuration in */etc/ssh/sshd_config*

> Port 22
>
> AddressFamily inet
>
> ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
>
> ListenAddress ::

I've changed AddressFamily from "any" to "inet".

Comment: I suggest editing cassandra-env.sh and uncommenting this line: `JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"`